# PHP MySql double quotes than single quotes

Tags: php, mysql

I was reading a book about PHP and saw this code for inserting records. I do not understand a specific expression in the default case of the ternary operator.  More specifically:

```
"'$v',"
```

Did the author make a mistake using single quotes (') and what he really meant were the backticks(`) to quote a soecial mysql expression? Why would you use single quotes and then double quotes on a variable?

According to the mysql documentation :

"The identifier quote character is the backtick (“`”): "
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

```
public function insertRecords($table, $data){
    //setup some variables for fields and values
    $fields = "";
    $values = "";

    //populate them
    foreach($data as $f => $v){
        $fields .= "`$f`,";
        $values .= (is_numeric($v) && (intval($v) == $v)) ? $v . "," : "'$v',";
    }
}
```

Comment: the single quotes are part of the db querry

Comment: not as an identifier but as a value... identifiers are names of db entities like tables and fields... values need to be wrapped in the prime ("'") character.

Comment: as in values('string', 'string');? I think I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double quotes signify that it's a string and the single quotes are part of a string.
inside double quotes variables are evaluated so the string will contain the value of the variable  'vValue' not '$v'

Answer (score 1):

The singlequotes wrap your value. It's important if the value is a String.

If you don't wrap the String-value, every word would be interpreted as a reserved SQL-word.

By the way, I recommend using PDO for handling SQL stuff: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

NOTE that the double quotes `" "` used in `(is_numeric($v) && (intval($v) == $v)) ? $v . "," : "'$v',";` are referring to the value inside a ternary operation.

```
`$values.=((is_numeric($v) && (intval($v) == $v)) ? $v . "," : "'$v',";`
```

is same as  saying:

```
if((is_numeric($v) && (intval($v) == $v)) {
$values.= $v . ",";
}else{
$values.="'$v',";
}
```

Which is practically correct....
You can learn more about ternary operators [here](http://phpmaster.com/using-the-ternary-operator/)::

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$values .= (is_numeric($v) && (intval($v) == $v)) ? $v . "," : "'$v',";
```

Looks to see if the value of $v is a number or not.  If it is a number it appends that number followed by a comma(,) to the value of $values.  If it is NOT a number then it wraps the value in single quotes followed by a comma and appends that to the $values.

Basically you are making sure your statement looks like this when it's all done:

```
insert into sometable (col1, col2, col3, col4) values (0, 'some string', 'other string', 67, 'etc...')
```